# Where are CMAKE_HOST_APPLE / CMAKE_HOST_UNIX / CMAKE_HOST_WIN32 set?

Tags: build, cmake, cross-platform, build-process

I've started digging in under the hood so that I can better understand the inner workings of CMake.  I've been going through the files in the Modules directory in order to understand how/why/when things happen when running CMake.

I've so far been unable to determine how/where the `CMAKE_HOST_APPLE`/`CMAKE_HOST_UNIX`/`CMAKE_HOST_WIN32` variables are set.

Can anyone enlighten me?

On a related note, I've been going through the Modules files in a haphazard manner since I don't know the order in which they are initiated/processed.

Is there anywhere that describes this flow or at the very least indicates a starting point so that I can figure out the rest from there?

Answer (score 1):

Those variables are set in CMake's code surrounded by platform dependent `#ifdef` checks, so you can say they are set during compile time of CMake itself.

I also had some difficulties locating the source file in question, because the code to add those default variable definitions has just recently moved from [`cmMakefile::AddDefaultDefinitions()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmMakefile.cxx) to [`cmState::Snapshot::SetDefaultDefinitions()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmState.cxx#L1365) (see this [commit](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/20b95ef8c83fbcb7705e72c85c9de18ff420562f)).

Here is an example from `cmState.cxx`:

> ```
> #if defined(__APPLE__)
>   this->SetDefinition("APPLE", "1");
>   this->SetDefinition("CMAKE_HOST_APPLE", "1");
> #endif
> ```

For more information on how CMake does work see:

- [CMake: In which Order are Files parsed (Cache, Toolchain, …)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)
- [How to frame the concept behind CMake?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299929/how-to-frame-the-concept-behind-cmake)

  - [About CMake](https://cmake.org/overview/)
  - [The Architecture of Open Source Applications: CMake](http://aosabook.org/en/cmake.html)