# moving CMake options from the command line into the top-level CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, dcmtk

I'm building DCMTK using the command line, using the following command:

```
cmake -DBUILD_APPS=BOOL:OFF ../latest_dcmtk
```

I want to move the BUILD_APPS setting from the command line into the top-level CMakeLists.txt configuration file.  No matter how I attempt set the BUILD_APPS option in the top level configuration file, I never get the correct behavior unless I explicitly set the BUILD_APPS option from the command line.

Is there a way to explicitly set command line options from the top-level CMakeLists.txt file?

I've borrowed this from the DCMTK sources & it doesn't work:

```
SET (BUILD_APPS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)                                                             
MESSAGE ("-- BUILD_APPS is set to " ${BUILD_APPS})
```

When I look at the CMakeCache.txt file that's generated by the SET command above, I see the option set correctly:

```
./CMakeCache.txt:BUILD_APPS:BOOL=OFF
```

Unfortunately, the option doesn't work.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Because DCMTK is a decent sized open-source project, I won't be able to strip the code down to a minimal example.  At best, I could provide the top-level CMake configuration file.  Even if I gave you that file, you'd need a Mac to build the equivalent project.

Comment: the example just has to consist of a stripped down CMakeLists.txt file with that option which is not working

Comment: Option set with command `option(BUILD_APPS "" OFF)` or `set(BUILD_APPS OFF CACHE BOOL "")` (FORCE is not needed) is equivalent for option set with `cmake` command line option `-DBUILD_APPS=BOOL:OFF`. If the second way works, but the first one doesn't, then `CMakeLists.txt` does something very special.

Comment: Just to be sure, I have given it a try again and the `-D` does force the Cache entry. So there should be no difference between using `-D` command line option and `set(... FORCE)`. I agree something is weird and suggest adding `variable_watch(BUILD_APPS)` at the top of the main `CMakeLists.txt` to find the codepart that is hiding/overwriting the variable. For more details see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables).

Comment: Where do you set the variable? At the very beginning or towards the end?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there are two things you have to keep in mind when using CMake:

1. CMake is a script language, so all code is processed sequential
2. The variable cache of CMake is there to persist values between two runs

So I agree with @Tsyvarev and @usr1234567 that this is most likely is an ordering issue:

- You have to do the `set(BUILD_APPS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)` before you/the code does check for `if (BUILD_APPS)`
- You have to check that there are no normal variable `set(BUILD_APPS ...)` afterwards in your main `CMakeLists.txt` hiding your cached variable
- Whatever is in the `CMakeCache.txt` file is only the state of those variables after all processing of your code has finished (at the end of your main `CMakeLists.txt`)

I have given it a try again and the `-D` does force the Cache entry. So there should be no difference between using `-D` command line option and `set(... CACHE ... FORCE)`. Just you can't use them in combination (the later will always overwrite any command line given option).

Please try adding [`variable_watch(BUILD_APPS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/variable_watch.html) at the top of the main `CMakeLists.txt` to find the codepart that is hiding/overwriting the variable.

**References**

- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)
- [CMake: In which Order are Files parsed (Cache, Toolchain, …)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)