# Override android.toolchain.cmake in Android cmake build

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

The cmake bundled with NDK is the one which gets used by default, but it defines so many options. One of them is -

```
elseif(ANDROID_STL STREQUAL gnustl_shared)
    set(ANDROID_STL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
        supc++)
    set(ANDROID_STL_SHARED_LIBRARIES
       gnustl_shared)
```

Now, I want gnustl_shared to used, but no supc++, and I cannot find anyway to do it. Removing it manually from android.toolchain.cmake works for me.
But I don't want to edit ndk toolchain cmake file on every machine.
In my app's cmakelists.txt, I have tried

```
list(FILTER ANDROID_STL_STATIC_LIBRARIES EXCLUDE REGEX ".*supc.*")
list(FILTER CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES_INIT EXCLUDE REGEX ".*supc.*")
```

But every time, in the generated build.ninja file, I see libsupc++.a in LINK_LIBRARIES.

Is there a clean way for me to exclude this lib while linking ?

Comment: When I look into `android.toolchain.cmake` I see that `ANDROID_STL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` is transferred to `ANDROID_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` which is used for `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`. So I would assume that modifying the later would solve your problem. But this is not a list, it's space separated. Have you tried something like `string(REPLACE "supc++" "" CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES}")`?

Comment: It worked !!!
Thanks a lot. But looking at ndk cmake file, how did you come to know ANDROID_STL_STATIC_LIBRARIES is going in CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES?? 
I couldnt find any such reference !!

Comment: You are welcome. In the version I had looked into, that was the case (I've linked the source in my answer). But even if it would be `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES_INIT` it will finally end up in `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

When I look into [`android.toolchain.cmake`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/cmake-utils/+/3c644e42f28687342c35632c466c06fb1bcaed03/android.toolchain.cmake#475) I see that `ANDROID_STL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` is transferred to `ANDROID_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` which is used for `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`.

So I modifying the later should solve your problem. But this is not a list, it's space separated and you should do:

```
string(REPLACE "supc++" "" CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES}")
```

**References**

- [CMake: In which Order are Files parsed (Cache, Toolchain, …)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)
- [`CMakeCXXInformation.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake#L220)