# CMake set toolchain variables

Tags: cmake, stm32

I am writing CMake for my project. It works fine, but every time when I want to use it, I have to specify some additional parameters:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="D:/stm32-cmake/cmake/gcc_stm32.cmake" -DSTM32_CHIP=STM32F207ZCT ..
```

Is it possible to save these parameters in CMakeLists.txt file? In my CMakeLists.txt I tried following options:

```
set(STM32_CHIP STM32F207ZCT)
set(STM32_CHIP STM32F207ZCT CACHE STRING "")
add_definitions(-DSTM32_CHIP=STM32F207ZCT)
```

But none of these seems to work. These parameters are used in toolchain file, so probably I have to set these variables globally in some way. 
And is it possibile to set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE in CMakeLists.txt? This code:

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/stm32-cmake/cmake/gcc_stm32.cmake")
```

is not working.

Comment: Solution suggested by @Florian is fine for me. This is what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: For more details see also ["CMake: In which Order are Files parsed (Cache, Toolchain, …)?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)